# Phrase searching to get only results for specific order and combination of words in QGIS documentation

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, search, documentation

The [official QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/) has a search function that is a bit tricky to use if you are looking for tools that consist of more than one word.

To make an example: searching for [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) - if you enter either `Geometry by Expression` (without quotes) or `"Geometry by Expression"` (with quotes), you get a long list of results that contain either `Geometry` or `Expression` or `Expressions` or all those words etc. However, the very combination `Geometry by Expression` is hidden somewhere in this long list of results.

Is there a way to limit the search to the specific order and combination of words ([phrase search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_search))?

*Search results contain a lot of entries that contain just a part of the search phrase:*

[image]

Comment: Noted and added in the Sphinx doc project in a future, not planified, version : https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a phrase search seems not to be implemented in the official QGIS documentation, there is a not-so-obvious option to overcome this limitation: in the Processing Toolbox, you can search for the tool (here, a kind of phrase search is realized), open the tool and then click the <kbd>Help</kbd> button. This opens the documentation for the tool.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I guess for the moment the quickest way is by following these two steps:

1. Search for your expression in the search field and hit enter
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in your browser to search for your expression in the result page returned by your query (redo for each page if results are paginated)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was doing up to now, but I hoped there is a better option as this is not ideal.

Comment: Indeed, but it's either undocumented or unimplemented by the website devs, but I found the code of the QGIS website on github once in the past, maybe you can check it out and see where the search is implemented. But I can easily imagine that there is a database part for the search component which is maybe not published. I don't know...

Answer (score 4):

A workaround, really not perfect (I just play around on this question).

Open a Linux terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute the script below:

```sh
# clone the QGIS Doc repo, do it once
git clone https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation.git
# if you want to refresh it
# git pull

cd QGIS-Documentation/

# variables
PHRASE="geometry by expression"
VERSION=3.28
LANG=en

# go on the required version branch
git checkout release_${VERSION}
# search the phrase and produce html links for the results
echo "https://docs.qgis.org/${VERSION}/${LANG}"$(grep -nrliF --include="*.rst" "${PHRASE}" ./docs/user_manual/ | sed -nE 's/^[.](.*)[.]rst/\1/p')".html"
```

Comment: This works for Linux only? Forgot to mention that I am on windows...

Comment: You can test it on WSL : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Comment: OK, maybe an overkill just to search in the docu. Still appreciate your effort, thanks a lot!